# Error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Network.so.5:

Tags: command-line, libraries, shared-library, octave, gnu

I was installing GNU octave on my Ubuntu 18.04 (from the terminal). After installation octave wouldn't open when I tried to launch it using the desktop icon. So I tried launching from the terminal and this showed up

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/octave/4.2.2/exec/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/octave-gui:
error while loading shared libraries:
libQt5Network.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried uninstalling/reinstalling with `sudo apt-get remove octave` and installed again after re-boot yet the problem persists.

I even tried this

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libqt5network5
```

But the result was

```
libqt5network5 is already the newest version (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1)
```

I'm confused that it says `no such file or directory` even though the relevant package is already installed

I'm not entirely sure about this but when I first installed octave it said around 300+ MB of data will be used for it. I left my computer on to install octave and returned after it finished. After I found this problem i uninstalled + reinstalled octave but when I was reinstalling it said 4,664 kB will be used.

Since I left my computer during installation I belive it went back to the login screen when I returned to see the installation was done. Is it possible that this corrupted the library?

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python3-distupgrade ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 139 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk all 1:18.04.22 [9,364 B]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core all 1:18.04.22 [24.4 kB]
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 python3-distupgrade all 1:18.04.22 [105 kB]
Fetched 139 kB in 3s (52.8 kB/s)              
(Reading database ... 199458 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk_1%3a18.04.22_all.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk (1:18.04.22) over (1:18.04.21) ...
Preparing to unpack .../ubuntu-release-upgrader-core_1%3a18.04.22_all.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (1:18.04.22) over (1:18.04.21) ...
Preparing to unpack .../python3-distupgrade_1%3a18.04.22_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-distupgrade (1:18.04.22) over (1:18.04.21) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
Setting up python3-distupgrade (1:18.04.22) ...
Setting up ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (1:18.04.22) ...
Setting up ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk (1:18.04.22) ...
```

---

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/octave/4.2.2/exec/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/octave-gui
    libQt5Network.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
```

---

```
$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d/* and env | grep LD, and ls -l /usr/lib/*/libQt5Network*
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf

# libc default configuration
/usr/local/lib
# Multiarch support
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/*/libQt5Network*': No such file or directory
```

---

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall libqt5network5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 634 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libqt5network5 amd64 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 [634 kB]
Fetched 634 kB in 30s (20.8 kB/s)                                              
(Reading database ... 196636 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libqt5network5_5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqt5network5:amd64 (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1) over (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libqt5network5:amd64 (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
```

i got another error with libQt5Widgets.so.5, and so i tried the same solution and it worked. Then i got an error with libQt5Gui.so.5 and i tried the same solution and it worked.

But then came libQt5Core.so.5. I tried the same thing i.e `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt install --reinstall libqt5core5`

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt install --reinstall libqt5core5
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]    
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]   
Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB] 
Hit:5 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease 
Fetched 247 kB in 3s (82.7 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libqt5core5
```

---

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/octave/4.2.2/exec/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/octave-gui | grep not
    libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
```

**Edit**: After some digging i found out the command to reinstall libqt5core was `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libqt5core5a` (I didnt know the "a" part).

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,035 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libqt5core5a amd64 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 [2,035 kB]
Fetched 2,035 kB in 19s (105 kB/s)                                             
(Reading database ... 201031 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libqt5core5a_5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqt5core5a:amd64 (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1) over (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libqt5core5a:amd64 (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
```

After installing it then I had more libs to install..
namely

```
libdouble-conversion.so.1
```

you can install it using

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libdouble-conversion1
```

then

```
libQt5Svg.so.5
```

installed using

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libqt5svg5
```

I suppose this *partially* fixed the problem but still has not solved it.
I can now open the CLI interface of octave using the command `/usr/bin/octave-cli` OR `octave-cli`

But when I simply run octave from the terminal, I get an error

```
octave exited with signal 6
```

I can't open Octave using the Desktop icon or the icon from Application menu yet.

**Edit**: Since I tried so many ways so fix the problem with little success i decided to just re-install my Ubuntu partition. With less fuss I got it all fixed. I assume it might have been a slow internet speed which might have ruined my Ubuntu installation the first time because this problem of shared libraries I had was common to other KDE-based packages like kile and okular. Re-installing fixed the problem so I'd suggest anyone who has less data to backup do so.

Comment: How did you installed Octave? Is it clean installation of Ubuntu or upgrade from previous version?

Comment: i installed octave using sudo apt-get install octave . I also installed Ubuntu 18.04  very recently (not an upgrade).

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue on clean 18.04 LTS. More details needed.

Comment: i edited my question. maybe it has to do something with interrupted installation when ubuntu locks out?

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get distupgrade` (add any error to the question), reboot and also add output of `ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/octave/4.2.2/exec/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/octave-gui | grep not` if error persists.

Comment: updated my question with results

Comment: I'm sorry, I had a typo, try `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` instead.

Comment: updated the results in the question. but no change yet

Comment: Please add to your question the output of `cat /etc/ld.so.conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*` and `env | grep LD`, and `ls -l /usr/lib/*/libQt5Network*`.

Comment: It seems that your repositories are completely wrong. You should have main, universe, multiverse. Got to `software-properties-gtk` and enable them (with *Updates*).

Comment: i just checked and its already enabled

Comment: @zwets i updated my question with the results (sorry for the delay i had to get off the internet for a while)

Comment: All looks OK, except that APT thinks you have libqt5network5 installed while it isn't. Try `apt install --reinstall libqt5network5`.

Comment: @zwets i tried exactly what you told me and i updated my question with the results.

Comment: can you display the result of `find / -type f -name "libQt5Network.so.5" 2>/dev/null
`? When you will have you result, just do `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:<path_find>` where`path_find` is the path you find with the `find` command

Comment: @damadam are those the right commands? , im not getting any results

Comment: @Suresh `export` didn't return any result, but `find` must return the path where you can find your librabry `libQt5Network.so.5`, so if you don't have any reult, you don't have `libQt5Network.so.5` on your computer

Comment: your package libQt5* uncompletely installed, try using 'apt-get purge libQt5* && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo init 6' and install again with 'apt-get install libQt5* '. hope this helps

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri i fixed it by reinstalling ubuntu 18.04